# how to calculate min outlining quadrilateral given 4 line segments

Tags: geometry

Yes, I know there are resources out there, but my question is slightly different. Given 4 arbitrary line segments, intersecting to form a quadrilateral, I need the MOST efficient (or at least highly effecient) method to calculate an outlining rectangle of the intersecting points. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: realized I worded my question wrong, fixed.

Comment: Do you mean your input is 4 coordinates in two pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$, or 4 pairs of coordinates ($x_1, y_1), \cdots, (x_4, y_4)$? It would be great if you could edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: Does the outlining rectangle need to be aligned with the axes?  If so, you just use the max and min $x$ values and the max and min $y$ values.  If not, the problem is harder.

Comment: Are we assuming that the quadrilateral in question is convex?

Comment: The title mentions some kind of minimality constraint, but the text just requests any outlining rectangle. So what do you want to minimize?

Comment: Just imagine 4 points (the intersections of the line segments). I just need an efficient way to get the minimum and maximum x and y values of the points that are used to create a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting four values is not hard.  Just sort the $x$ values of the four points and take the minimum for the lower left corner and the maximum for the upper right.  Sort the $y$ values and take the minimum for the lower left and the maximum of for the lower right.  You can do each sort with at most five compares